# How to create a mail template for Outlook from an existing HTML file. The template should let the user replace the images

Tags: html, email, outlook

I have a problem about microsoft outlook. How to create a mail template for Outlook from an existing HTML file. The template should let the user replace the images...

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

1. Click on "New Email"
2. Click "Attach File" on the "Insert" tab
3. Select your HTML file
4. Choose "Insert As Text" from the "Insert" drop down menu
5. Choose "Save As" from the "File" Tab
6. Choose "Outlook Template"
7. Type the name for your template - done!

***Note:*** *You can simply replace images by right-clicking on them and choosing "Change Image"*